# Rust lifetimes: can't re-borrow mutable field inside a method

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm trying to write a data structure `ScopedSet` that mutably borrows a `HashSet`, adding an element to it, and then removes that element when the `ScopedSet` is dropped:

```rust
let mut s = HashSet::new();
if let Some(mut s) = ScopedSet::new_with(&mut s, 1) {
    // Do something knowing `s.set` contains `1`
}
// `s` no longer contains `1`
```

I managed to get a working implementation for this:

```rust
use std::collections::HashSet;
use std::cmp::Eq;
use std::hash::Hash;

struct ScopedSet<'s, T: Eq + Hash> {
    value: T,
    set: &'s mut HashSet<T>,
}

impl<'s, T: Eq + Hash> Drop for ScopedSet<'s, T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        self.set.remove(&self.value);
    }
}

impl<'s, T: Clone + Eq + Hash> ScopedSet<'s, T> {
    fn new_with(set: &'s mut HashSet<T>, value: T) -> Option<Self> {
        if set.insert(value.clone()) {
            Some(Self { value, set })
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

However, trouble arises when I try to do stacked borrows.  I can do the following:

```rust
if let Some(mut s) = ScopedSet::new_with(&mut s, 1) {
    if let Some(mut s) = ScopedSet::new_with(&mut s.set, 2) {
        // Do something knowing `s.set` contains both `1` and `2`
    }
};
```

but I would like to have a method on `ScopedSet` that would allow me to do this:

```rust
if let Some(mut s) = ScopedSet::new_with(&mut s, 1) {
    if let Some(mut s) = s.with(2) {
        // Do something knowing `s.set` contains both `1` and `2`
    }
};
```

I haven't found a way to write `ScopedSet::with` that's accepted by the borrow checker.  For example:

```rust
impl<'s, T: Clone + Eq + Hash> ScopedSet<'s, T> {
    fn with<'a, 'b>(&'a mut self, value: T) -> Option<ScopedSet<'b, T>>
    where
        's: 'a,
        'a: 'b,
    {
        if self.set.insert(value.clone()) {
            Some(Self {
                value,
                set: &mut self.set,
            })
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

Here, the rational is that I want to create a `ScopedSet` containing a borrow `&'b mut HashSet<T>` which is outlived by the parent `ScopedSet` borrow (`&'a mut self`), giving me `'a: 'b`.  I also know that the parent borrow must be outlived by the data borrow `&'s mut HashSet<T>`, so we have `'s: 'a`.  Unfortunately, this does not compile:

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:35:22
   |
26 | impl<'s, T: Clone + Eq + Hash> ScopedSet<'s, T> {
   |      -- lifetime `'s` defined here
27 |     fn with<'a, 'b>(&'a mut self, value: T) -> Option<ScopedSet<'b, T>>
   |             -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
35 |                 set: &mut self.set,
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this usage requires that `'a` must outlive `'s`
   |
   = help: consider adding the following bound: `'a: 's`
```

Does anybody have an idea of how I could get `ScopedSet::with` working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your implementation is very simple: you're using `Self` where you need to use `ScopedSet`.

This:

```rust
Some(Self {
    value,
    set: &mut self.set,
})
```

Needs to be this:

```rust
Some(ScopedSet {
    value,
    set: &mut self.set,
})
```

And it will work.

`Self` in the context of the implementation is `ScopedSet<'s, T>`, but you need  `ScopedSet<'b, T>`.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't realize this.  Thanks a lot!